# How to wrap selected text with tags in VS Code and repeat the action efficiently?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

All `<p>` tags were stripped from the markup of a document which provided the whitespace formatting. I need to add back the `<p>` tags with a css class. The document is nearly 300 lines.

Is it possible to create an action/automation/key binding within VSCode to quickly wrap selected text with open/close tags plus a class? To clarify, I would like to select some text and use an action to wrap a pre-defined tag and a class around it, repeating the process for each line.

`ctrl` + `shift` + `p` - **Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation** is the manual solution although not considered time-saving imo, as I need to enter in the tag and class each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make a simple keybinding (in keybindings.json):

```
{
  "key": "alt+m",                                //whatever keybinding you choose
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  // "when": "resourceExtname == .html",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "<p class=\"myClass\">$TM_SELECTED_TEXT</p>"
  }
}
```

If your class changes you could put a tabstop there instead of hardcoding a particular className:

`"snippet": "<p class=\"$1\">$TM_SELECTED_TEXT</p>"`

It will work for multi-cursors too.  Only the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> is for triggering the snippet.  The other keystrokes are just to set multiple cursors and then expand those selections - which you may not need.  I don't know how you are selecting each of your cases.

[image: wrap with class snippet]

Comment: Well done, works as intended! I appreciate the time you took to submit an answer.