# HTML surround with Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, tags, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a paragraph, `<p> hello world</p>` and now I want to put the "world" inside a `<em></em>.`
I am looking for a shortcut to mark the word and write the `<em>`.
And I won’t have to delete and replace the word I want.

How can I do it?

Comment: is this question about VS Code? or Visual Studio? They are not the same thing. if it's about VS Code, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/46854557/11107541

Comment: @peter I was actually waiting for the asker to clarify whether this is about VS or VS Code. If you saw my comment and decided to make that presumption, you should have dup-voted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Emmet shortcuts to write speed up your code writing.

Things like:

`p>{hello world}` will expand to `<p>Hello world</p>`

And then:

`em>{world}` will become `<em>world</em>`

If you want to do all together:
`p>{hello}+em>{world}` which will be then expanded to `<p>hello<em>world</em></p>`

You can read more here:

1. *[Emmet — the essential toolkit for web-developers](https://docs.emmet.io/)* (official site)
2. *[Emmet in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet)*

Answer (score 0):

- select the text `world`
- use the command **Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation**
- type `em` and `Enter`

If you need to do it often with the same abbreviations you can use an extension I wrote: [Recently Used](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-recently-used). In the extension settings you can predefine abbreviations.

Comment: if you think this question is about VS Code, I suggest you move your answer to the older and more highly upvoted https://stackoverflow.com/q/58169567/11107541, which is actually about efficient repetition. without the efficient repetition part, then you should be dup-voting to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46854557/11107541.